# Kendo UI MVC datepicker localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, kendo-ui, datepicker

Kendo UI culture set to fr-CA.

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<script src="~/Content/KendoUI/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/KendoUI/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/KendoUI/js/cultures/kendo.culture.fr-CA.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        kendo.culture('fr-CA');
    });
</script>
```

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture fnd Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture are set to "fr-CA".

**Datepicker formatted to "MMM dd, yyyy"**:

```
    @{
            Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.DateFrom)
            .Format("MMM dd, yyyy")
            .ParseFormats(new List<string> { "MMM dd, yyyy" })
            .Enable(true)
            .Render();
     }
```

Dates are shown in the correct format and the calendar is localized, but it displays an error when you pick the date:
"The field Dater de must be a date."

The error occures only if you select french-specific date (e.g. déc. 16, 2013), for dates which are the same for english and french (e.g. nov. 25, 2013) it works correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **globalize.js**. Here is the link: https://github.com/jquery/globalize/releases

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.fr-CA.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        jQuery.global = Globalize;
        $.global.culture('fr-CA');
        $.validator.focusInvalid = true;
        $.validator.methods.date = function(value) {
            if (value == '' || !isNaN($.global.parseDate(value))) return true;
            return false;
        };
    });
</script>
```